# Laravel 5.4 not setting default id in get router

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I am learning Laravel and I am trying to set a default value for $id.

Example:

```
Route::get('/user/{id?}/', function ($id=1) {
    echo 'user '. $id;
});
```

However, when I open `http://localhost/laravel/blog/public/user`, I only see `user` instead of `user 1`. Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: because `$id` will always be passed to the function even if it is empty, therefore the default will not be assigned.

Comment: Okay I see how this might be the reason but in the tutorial I am watching it works. Do you think they changed something in a later version?

Comment: I have a similar route `/test/{id?}`, navigating to `/test` shows `Test: 1` (as `$id = 1` is in the function declaration like yours) and navigating to `/test/5` shows `Test: 5`; basically, I can't recreate this. Do you have any other routes in your file that could be conflicting with this?

Comment: Also @Joe That's incorrect; an optional URL parameter like `{id?}` doesn't work like that; if it's in the URL, it'll be assigned, otherwise it will default to whatever's in the function declaration, so it _should_ be `user 1`.

Comment: What would `var_dump($id)` output if you put it before echo?

Comment: @TimLewis OMG! Yes, I had another `Route::get('/user', function () {` in the same file from testing I did earlier. After removing it, the default value `1` is now shown when I go to `http://localhost/laravel/blog/public/user`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome; glad you got that working. Routes can be difficult sometimes, especially when you start getting into wildcard routes where you chain multiple URL parameters. Rule of thumb though is put routes with optional parameters underneath those without to avoid possible conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('test/{id?}', function($id = 1) {
    echo 'test '.$id;
});
```

This works for me. If I go to `foo.com/test/2`, it outputs `test 2`, if I type `foo.com/test`, it outputs `test 1`